# Checking a number with calculator package

Tags: calculations

I have a problem about `calculator` package, I need check if `#1` is a number or not, could I use conditional command?
ex:

```
\def\CHECK#1{

% if #1 a number

\if...?

 #1 is a number

\else

 #1 is not a number

\fi

}

\CHECK{3}

\CHECK{n}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! There's no need to 'shout' (i.e. using uppercase words ;-))

Comment: `number` isn't unique -- I think, you mean an integer number? Knowing more of the context would be helpful.

Comment: It's the first time that I ask my question. I'm bad at english. Forgive me! Thanks, 
I can check \ifnum #1 = 0,1, 2 ... etc, but I can't check #1 is a interger or not. Which command if could I use?

Comment: @phanttam: [`calculator`](http://ctan.org/pkg/calculator) seems to accept both integer and floating point numbers. As such, the linked post should suffice to check whether the input to `calculator` functions are (not) acceptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is perhaps too much, but I tried to use `l3regex` and checking whether the argument of `#1` contains any non-digit using the 'negative class' `[^0-9]` as regular expression.

A better approach would use a conditional, but until the context isn't clear, I restrict to this solution.

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{l3regex}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\newcommand{\CHECK}[1]{
  \regex_match:nnTF {[^0-9]} {#1}{
    #1~is~not~an~integer}{
    #1~is~a~integer}
}% End of \CHECK definition
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\CHECK{1234234}

\CHECK{foo}

\CHECK{234.4523}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I need if #1 is not a integer number

[latex]\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}2^k=1+2+2^2+\ldots+2^{n-1}+2^n[/latex] 

else

[latex]\sum\limits_{k=0}^{2016}2^k=1+2+2^2+\ldots+2^{2015}+2^2016
[/latex]

I need check a number that I can 

[code]\def \SUM#1{

% check #1 is a number or not, if #1 is a number

$\sum\limits_{k=0}^{#1}2^k=1+2+2^2+\ldots+2^{\SUBTRACT{#1}{1}
{\sol}\sol}+2^{#1}$
\else
$\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}2^k=1+2+2^2+\ldots+2^{n-1}+2^n$
\fi
}
\SUM{n}
\SUM{2016}
[/code]

Which conditional command can use?

Comment: @phanttam: Please add this to your question, it would clearify the question (and perhaps closing it)